# BestBefore puzzle test cases

Tags: java, testing

I have written the following piece of code for this [puzzle](http://www.spotify.com/us/jobs/tech/best-before/). I have come up with a list of test inputs I think cover all the cases and the code passes all of them. But the bot does not accept my answer. For the love of FSM, I need closure on this so that I can sleep tonight. Can anyone suggest a test case which my code will fail?

Main Class:

```
package bestBefore;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class BestBefore {

    private String d_inputDate;
    private List<Date> d_validDateList ;
    private static String s_dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static DateFormat s_df ;
    private static Calendar s_upperBoundary ;
    private static Calendar s_lowerBoundary ; 

    static {
        s_df = new SimpleDateFormat(s_dateFormat);
        s_df.setLenient(false);
        s_upperBoundary = new GregorianCalendar();

            s_upperBoundary.clear();
        s_upperBoundary.set(3000,Calendar.JANUARY,1);
        s_lowerBoundary = new GregorianCalendar();
            s_lowerBoundary.clear();
        s_lowerBoundary.set(1999,Calendar.DECEMBER,31);
    }


    public static void main ( String[] args ) {

        String inputDate = "";;
        if ( args.length == 0 ){
            //sop("Usage: java BestBefore <input_date>");
            try {
                BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                inputDate = stdin.readLine();
            }catch (IOException ioe) {
                sop(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            inputDate = args[0];
        }

        BestBefore bb = new BestBefore(inputDate);
        sop(bb.getEarliestDate());
    }

    public BestBefore ( String inputDate ) {
        d_inputDate = inputDate;
        d_validDateList = new ArrayList<Date> ();
        processDate();
    }


    private void processDate() {

        if ( d_inputDate == null)
            return;

        String[] dates = d_inputDate.split("/");
        int[] datesInt = new int[3];  // to store the parseInts

        if( dates.length !=3 ) {
            return;
        }

        int yearInd = -1;
        try {
        // check if any 4 digits , then that is the year and also integer parse
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < dates.length ; i ++ ) {

            if(dates[i].length() == 3)
                return;

            //Covnert to int 
            datesInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(dates[i].trim());

            if (datesInt[i] > 31){ // if number greater than 31 then year  : TODO check month too and avoid looops
                if ( yearInd == -1) {
                    yearInd = i;
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
            }


            // Check for negative numbers
            if ( datesInt[i] < 0 ) {
                return;
            }
        }


        //ProcesDates
        if ( yearInd != -1 )  // we have a year / cuts down number of date parses by factor of 3
            haveYear(datesInt,yearInd);
        else
            noYear(datesInt);

    }catch (Exception e ) { // not a number
        return;
    }

    }


    private void haveYear(int[] dates, int yearInd ) {
        String dateToParse = padYear(dates[yearInd]+"") + "-";
        int[] mD = new int[2];

        for ( int i = 0,j = 0   ; i < dates.length ; i ++ ) {
            if ( i == yearInd ) 
                continue;
            mD[j] = dates[i] ;
            j++;
        }

        // parse date and rotate  and repeat
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < mD.length ; i ++ ) {
            try { 
                Date date = s_df.parse( dateToParse+mD[0]+"-"+mD[1] );
                if ( (s_lowerBoundary.getTime()).before(date) && (s_upperBoundary.getTime().after(date)))
                    d_validDateList.add(date );
            }catch ( Exception e ) {
                // Not a valid date
                continue;
            }finally {
                mD = rotate(mD);
            }
        }
    }

    private void noYear(int[] dates){
        // parse  and repeat
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < dates.length ; i ++ ) {
            haveYear( dates, i );
        }
    }

    public String getEarliestDate( ) {

        try{
            Date earliestDate = null;

            if (d_validDateList.size() == 0) {
                return d_inputDate+" is illegal";
            }

            // get the earliest date
            for ( Date dt : d_validDateList ) {
                if ( earliestDate == null ) {
                    earliestDate  = dt;
                    continue;
                }
                if ( dt.before(earliestDate) )
                    earliestDate = dt ;
            }

            return (s_df.format(earliestDate)) ;
        }
        catch(Exception e ){
            return d_inputDate+" is illegal";
        }


    }



    //
    // Static utility methods follow
    //

    private static void sop ( String message ) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private static int[] rotate(int[] a){
        if (a.length ==0 )
            return a;

        int firstElement = a[0];

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.length-1 ; i ++ ) {
            a[i]= a[i+1];
        }
        a[a.length-1] = firstElement;
        return a;
    }

    private static String padYear(String s ){
        if ( s.length() > 3) 
            return s;

        String frt =  (String.format("2%1$#3s", s)).replace(" ","0");
        return ( frt) ;
    }

    // Invalid Date Exception Class


}
```

Test Class:

```
  package bestBefore;


public class BestBeforeTest {

    private static String[] dta = {"01/01/01",
        "999/12/31",
        "12/12/12",
        "0/0/0",
        "4/1/5",
        "999/12/12",
        "10/11/12",
        "qwe/1/1",
        "-1/10/10",
        "1000/1/1",
        "2100/2/29",
        "31/11/76",
        "2400/2/29",
        "2404/2/29",
        "2401/2/29",
        "",
        "1/1/",
        "000000000000/ /",
        "1/1/1.0",
        "1/1/1",
        "1/2/3",
        "30/5/09",
        "26/12/12",
        "36/12/12",
        "0\3\33",
        "1.1/3.0/3",
        "999/31/12",
        "1/1/000",
    "02/4/67",
"",
"unknown", 
"2012-10-10", 
"20121010", 
"2012/10/10/",
    "2012/10/10" ,
    "2012/1/10",
    "2012/10/1", "12/10/10", "2/10/10",
    "2/10",
    "2",
            "31/12/2999",
            "1/1/3000"
    };

    public static void main ( String[] args){

        for ( int i = 0; i < dta.length ; i ++ )    {
            BestBefore bb = new BestBefore(dta[i]);
            System.out.println(bb.getEarliestDate());
        }
    }
}
```

Test Results:

```
2001-01-01
999/12/31 is illegal
2012-12-12
0/0/0 is illegal
2001-04-05
999/12/12 is illegal
2010-11-12
qwe/1/1 is illegal
-1/10/10 is illegal
1000/1/1 is illegal
2100/2/29 is illegal
31/11/76 is illegal
2400-02-29
2404-02-29
2401/2/29 is illegal
 is illegal
1/1/ is illegal
000000000000/ / is illegal
1/1/1.0 is illegal
2001-01-01
2001-02-03
2005-09-30
2012-12-26
2036-12-12
0 is illegal
1.1/3.0/3 is illegal
999/31/12 is illegal
1/1/000 is illegal
2/10 is illegal
2067-02-04
 is illegal
unknown is illegal
2012-10-10 is illegal
20121010 is illegal
2012-10-10
2012-10-10
2012-01-10
2012-01-10
2010-10-12
2002-10-10
2/10 is illegal
2 is illegal
2999-12-31
1/1/3000 is illegal
null is illegal
```

Thanks All. I believe this will be a good learning experience in coming up with test cases.

Comment: The spec implies that a 3-digit year should be rejected, not padded with a 2.

Comment: @DavidWallace This is the only discrepancy I saw as well - you should make it an answer

Comment: @DavidWallace ,If only that was the case; I would have only had a lesson in Spec reading, but I guess there are more lessons for me to learn. The Bot still rejects after your help.

Comment: I have the suspicion that your code would reject `31/12/2999`, although it should accept it. I don't know if the `after` method is weird, however, and says today is after today.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer . I have thought and tried that test case and my program gives the correct output for it. I have edited my question to reflect that. I believe it is because when the new GreogrianCalendar() object is created, it will have the HH:mm:ss.SSS of that machine time instance and I only over write yyyy-MM-dd part of it. I realize that this case would fail if this program is run exactly when machine time is at  HH:mm:ss.SSS and I should handle that .But it  should still pass the rest of the time.

Answer (score 1):

how about below code:

```
public static void main ( String[] args){

  for ( int i = 0; i < dta.length ; i ++ )    {
    BestBefore bb = new BestBefore(***null***);
    System.out.println(bb.getEarliestDate());
  }

}
```

so your test case should include special cases exhaustively. e.g.

```
null
""
"unknown"
"2012-10-10"
"20121010"
"2012/10/10/"

"2012/10/10"
"2012/1/10"
"2012/10/1"
"12/10/10"
"2/10/10"
"2/10"
"2"
```

Comment: null was a good suggestion. I have edited my test case and results and added them to the test case and my code seems to process them correctly.Thanks.